# Добавить заказ + вызвать woocommerce_new_order WooCommerce PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

CRM система выгружает заказы из WooCommerce, используя событие `woocommerce_new_order`.
Создаю заказ средствами PHP, мне нужно, чтобы он попал в CRM систему, однако этого не происходит, видимо событие не срабатывает. Как нужно сделать?

```
  ## Создаем заказ
  $prodIds = explode(';', $prodIds);

  global $woocommerce;

  $address = array(
    'first_name' => $name,
    'phone'      => $phone,
    'country'    => 'RU'
  );

  // 
  $order = wc_create_order();

  for ($i=0; $i < count($prodIds)-1 ; $i++) {
    $order->add_product( get_product($prodIds[$i]), 1);
  }
  $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
  //
  $order->calculate_totals();
  $order->update_status("pending", 'Купить в 1 клик', TRUE);
  do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order->get_id() );
```

Comment: А вы дебажили код? По всей логике кода должно было отработать. Метод этот точно вызывается?

Comment: Вопрос надо закрывать, потому что "интеграция" с CRM не описана никак. Там может быть (и явно есть) тонна ошибок. Потому что do_action() в WP - работает.

Comment: В качестве причины закрытия вопроса я указал отсутствие минимального воспроизводимого примера.